# How to select covered objects via mouse in fabricJS?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, selection, fabricjs

I'm trying to develop a way to select objects that are layered below and (totally) covered by other objects. One idea is to select the top object and then via `doubleclick` walk downwards through the layers. This is what I got at the moment:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");

fabric.util.addListener(canvas.upperCanvasEl, "dblclick", function (e) {
  var _canvas = canvas;
  var _mouse = _canvas.getPointer(e);
  var _active = _canvas.getActiveObject();
    
  if (e.target) {
    var _targets = _canvas.getObjects().filter(function (_obj) {
      return _obj.containsPoint(_mouse);
    });
      
    //console.warn(_targets);
      
    for (var _i=0, _max=_targets.length; _i<_max; _i+=1) {
      //check if target is currently active
      if (_targets[_i] == _active) {
        //then select the one on the layer below
        _targets[_i-1] && _canvas.setActiveObject(_targets[_i-1]);
         break;
        }
      }
    }
});

canvas
  .add(new fabric.Rect({
    top: 25,
    left: 25,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: "red"
  }))
  .add(new fabric.Rect({
    top: 50,
    left: 50,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: "green"
  }))
  .add(new fabric.Rect({
    top: 75,
    left: 75,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: "blue"
  }))
  .renderAll();
```

```css
canvas {
 border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

As you can see, trying to select the `red` rectangle from within the `blue` one is not working. I'm only able to select the `green` or the `blue`. I guess that after the first `doubleclick` worked (`green` is selected), clicking again just selects `blue` so the following doubleclick is only able to get `green` again.

**Is there a way around this? Any other ideas?**

Comment: **"Any other ideas?"** Sure, if a FabricJS hit test of multiple-layered rectangles is not readily available, just iterate through the rects and mathematically test if the mouseX,mouseY is inside any rect. See this Html5-Canvas [Documentation Example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html5-canvas/5017/collisions-and-intersections/17716/is-an-x-y-point-inside-a-rectangle#t=201608240434175724158). This way you don't need to try to coordinate clicks & doubleclicks & tripleclicks, etc. ;-)

Comment: @markE: That's not addressing my problem. I already know which objects are hit by the mouse pointer (these are my `_targets` in the code above). I need a mechanism to `select` objects that are covered by others. And the one beneath, and so on.

Comment: I'm no FabricJS guru but can't you select a group of objects with `fabric.Group`?  `var group = new fabric.Group(); group.addWithUpdate(targetObject); canvas.setActiveObject(group); canvas.add(group);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some time I finally was able to solve that by myself. Clicking on an object brings it to the top. On double-clicking I try to get the object one layer behind the current object. On another dblclick I get the one behind and so on. Works great for me and also allows for the selection of fully covered objects without the need to move others.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");

canvas.on("object:selected", function (e) {
  if (e.target) {
    e.target.bringToFront();
    this.renderAll();
  }
});

var _prevActive = 0;
var _layer = 0;

//
fabric.util.addListener(canvas.upperCanvasEl, "dblclick", function (e) {
    var _canvas = canvas;
    //current mouse position
    var _mouse = _canvas.getPointer(e);
    //active object (that has been selected on click)
    var _active = _canvas.getActiveObject();
    //possible dblclick targets (objects that share mousepointer)
    var _targets = _canvas.getObjects().filter(function (_obj) {
        return _obj.containsPoint(_mouse) && !_canvas.isTargetTransparent(_obj, _mouse.x, _mouse.y);
    });
    
    _canvas.deactivateAll();
      
    //new top layer target
    if (_prevActive !== _active) {
        //try to go one layer below current target
        _layer = Math.max(_targets.length-2, 0);
    }
    //top layer target is same as before
    else {
        //try to go one more layer down
        _layer = --_layer < 0 ? Math.max(_targets.length-2, 0) : _layer;
    }

    //get obj on current layer
    var _obj = _targets[_layer];

    if (_obj) {
     _prevActive = _obj;
     _obj.bringToFront();
     _canvas.setActiveObject(_obj).renderAll();
    }
});

//create something to play with
canvas
  //fully covered rect is selectable with dblclicks
  .add(new fabric.Rect({
    top: 75,
    left: 75,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    fill: "black",
    stroke: "black",
    globalCompositeOperation: "xor",
    perPixelTargetFind: true
  }))
  .add(new fabric.Circle({
    top: 25,
    left: 25,
    radius: 50,
    fill: "rgba(255,0,0,.5)",
    stroke: "black",
    perPixelTargetFind: true
  }))
  .add(new fabric.Circle({
    top: 50,
    left: 50,
    radius: 50,
    fill: "rgba(0,255,0,.5)",
    stroke: "black",
    perPixelTargetFind: true
  }))
  .add(new fabric.Circle({
    top: 75,
    left: 75,
    radius: 50,
    fill: "rgba(0,0,255,.5)",
    stroke: "black",
    perPixelTargetFind: true
  }))
  .renderAll();
```

```css
canvas {
 border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Try perPixelTargetFind

When fdirst creating the object, add an additional property:

```
perPixelTargetFind: true
```

Docs: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#perPixelTargetFind

*When set to `true`, objects are "found" on canvas on per-pixel basis rather than according to bounding box*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My task is a bit different - the mission is to pick the overlapping obj behind the current one:

1. [Left-click]+[Cmd-Key] on an selected-object to pick the first overlapping object which is right behind it.
2. If no overlapping objs are found, restart the search from top-layer

The idea is, for each click-event, intercept the selected object and replace it with our desired object.

A Fabric `mouse-down` event is like this:

1. User clicks on canvas
2. On canvas: find the `target-obj` by the coordinates of mouse cursor and stores it in the instance-variable (canvas._target)
3. Run event-handlers for `mouse:down:before`
4. Compare the `target-obj` found from step(2) with current selected object, fire `selection:cleared/update/create` events according to the results of comparison.
5. Set new activeObject(s)
6. Run event-handlers for `mouse:down`

We can use a customized event handler on `mouse:down:before` to intercept the `target-obj` found on Step(2) and replace it by our desired-object

```js
fCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('my-canvas', {
  backgroundColor: '#cbf1f1',
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  preserveObjectStacking: true
})

const r1 = new fabric.Rect({ width: 200, height: 200, stroke: null, top: 0, left: 0, fill:'red'})
const r2 = new fabric.Rect({ width: 200, height: 200, stroke: null, top: 50, left: 50, fill:'green'})
const r3 = new fabric.Rect({ width: 200, height: 200, stroke: null, top: 100, left: 100, fill:'yellow'})

fCanvas.add(r1, r2, r3)
fCanvas.requestRenderAll()

fCanvas.on('mouse:down:before', ev => {
  if (!ev.e.metaKey) {
    return
  }
  // Prevent conflicts with multi-selection
  if (ev.e[fCanvas.altSelectionKey]) {
    return
  }
  const currActiveObj = fCanvas.getActiveObject()
  if (!currActiveObj) {
    return
  }

  const pointer = fCanvas.getPointer(ev, true)
  const hitObj = fCanvas._searchPossibleTargets([currActiveObj], pointer)
  if (!hitObj) {
    return
  }

  let excludeObjs = []
  if (currActiveObj instanceof fabric.Group) {
    currActiveObj._objects.forEach(x => { excludeObjs.push(x) })
  } else {
    // Target is single active object
    excludeObjs.push(currActiveObj)
  }

  let remain = excludeObjs.length
  let objsToSearch = []
  let lastIdx = -1
  const canvasObjs = fCanvas._objects

  for (let i = canvasObjs.length-1; i >=0 ; i--) {
    if (remain === 0) {
      lastIdx = i
      break
    }
    const obj = canvasObjs[i]
    if (excludeObjs.includes(obj)) {
      remain -= 1
    } else {
      objsToSearch.push(obj)
    }
  }

  const headObjs = canvasObjs.slice(0, lastIdx+1)
  objsToSearch = objsToSearch.reverse().concat(headObjs)
  const found = fCanvas._searchPossibleTargets(objsToSearch, pointer)
  if (found) {
    fCanvas._target = found
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.3.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
<html>
<h4>Left-click + Cmd-key on overlapping area to pick the obj which is behind current one</h4>
<canvas id="my-canvas"></canvas>

</html>
```