# How to click through a fabricjs object to select object under it (without using evented property)

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas, fabricjs

How do you make a fabricjs object "locked" such that:

1. It's not selectable (obj.selectable = false)
2. Allows 'mousedown' event for right-click (obj.evented must be true)
3. No hover state/event (mouse does not detect this obj on hovering or changes the cursor)
4. Allows mouse to click objects under it (mouse can access objects through it)

I tried looking for the code that deals with the 'evented' prop but I could not find it in the source. The evented property does make the object transparent (ie. able to click through it), but removes the 'mousedown' event.

This is needed in my situation where I need to implement a context menu with lock/unlock object feature. If the object is locked, you still need to be able to right-click on it to display the context menu again so you can unlock it. Also, when locked, you need to be able to access and click objects under it.

Fabricjs 3.6.6

**Edit:**
I'm told that this is not possible out of the box by fabric and some custom code must be written to add this capability, as per:
https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/6734

Comment: Possible duplicates of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39102493/how-to-select-covered-objects-via-mouse-in-fabricjs

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The issue that you linked does not address what I am trying to achieve. I do not want the locked object (that covers the other object) to have any mouse interactions or be selectable. I only need to right click over it and get it's instance. Evented=false removes all events so this does not help me. And your linked issue is a selectable object.

Comment: Why can't `evented` be `false`, per #2?  Right clicks trigger the `contextmenu` event, which I don't think fabricJS attempts to handle (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event).

Comment: @ Ben evented cannot be false because I need the fabricjs mousedown event, not the browser/client contextmenu event. I need the fabricjs event because it will give me the fabric object as the event target being right-clicked. The contextmenu client event will give me the html element as the target. I need the Fabric object.